# the method 'fromjson' isn't defined for the type 'type'

Tags: flutter, dart, retrofit, pojo

The method 'fromJson' isn't defined for the type 'Type'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'fromJson'

this below code is in **Retrofit.g.dart** file

```
@override
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> signupCustomerRegistration(customerReg) async {
    ArgumentError.checkNotNull(customerReg, 'customerReg');
    const _extra = <String, dynamic>{};
    final queryParameters = <String, dynamic>{};
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data.addAll(customerReg?.toJson() ?? <String, dynamic>{});
    final _result = await _dio.request<Map<String, dynamic>>(
        '/api/API/CustomerSignUp',
        queryParameters: queryParameters,
        options: RequestOptions(
            method: 'POST',
            headers: <String, dynamic>{},
            extra: _extra,
            baseUrl: baseUrl),
        data: _data);
    var value = _result.data.map((k, dynamic v) =>
        MapEntry(k, dynamic.fromJson(v as Map<String, dynamic>)));

    return value;
  }
```

My **Model File code** is below:

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final customerReg = customerRegFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'CustomerRegModel.g.dart';


@JsonSerializable()
class CustomerRegModel {
  CustomerRegModel({
    this.custUid,
    this.appname,
    this.blacklist,
    this.custEmail,
    this.custName,
    this.custPhone,
    this.fcmToken,
    this.password,
    this.agentnin,
    this.source,
    this.signupDate,
    this.commStartTime,
    this.commEndTime,
    this.commMaxValue,
    this.commMinValue,
    this.commDownValue,
    this.walletamount,
  });

  String custUid;
  String appname;
  bool blacklist;
  String custEmail;
  String custName;
  String custPhone;
  String fcmToken;
  String password;
  String agentnin;
  String source;
  int signupDate;
  int commStartTime;
  int commEndTime;
  int commMaxValue;
  int commMinValue;
  int commDownValue;
  int walletamount;

  factory CustomerRegModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$CustomerRegModelFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$CustomerRegModelToJson(this);
  
  CustomerRegModel customerRegModelFromJson(String str) => CustomerRegModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));
  String customerRegModelToJson(CustomerRegModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());
}
```

**Tried:**

- Invalidate Caches and Restart.
- Deleting .g.dart files and recreating it.
- Have implemented same Code for other models with retrofit and working fine just not working on this.

Comment: What is `dynamic.fromJson`? You can't use `dynamic` like this.

Comment: Exactly, replace dynamic.fromJson with CustomerRegModel.fromJson

Comment: It is creating itself with build runner command for Retrofit.g.dart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so after doing research and creating an issue in Github Retrofit (https://github.com/trevorwang/retrofit.dart/issues/327) which they didn't respond, i went for searching parsing Json to Map and i found solution to my problem.

i.e:

For Retrofit Configuration:-

```
  @GET("/api/API/CustomerLogin")
  Future<String> loginCustomer(@Query('id') String email_or_number,
  @Query('pass') String pass, @Query('check') String check);
```

Notice above that i used String as response. Now i will convert String into Map using json.decode method.

```
final response = await client.loginCustomer(email_or_number,pass,check);
final Map<String,dynamic> map = json.decode(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by using a dependency override for code_builder.
You don't need to replace HttpResonse for String with this solution.

dependency_overrides:
code_builder: ^4.3.0

https://github.com/trevorwang/retrofit.dart/issues/505